# How do I replace chars in a String at a certain location in Java?

Tags: java, string, indexing, char

Okay, so I have a String lets say "abcd". Now I need to be able to put bracets like this [], around a certain location. For example, if input is 0 (as in index 0), then it returns a String that holds "[a]bcd" or if the input is 2, then it returns "ab[c]d". How would I go about implementing this is Java? Is there a method in the String class already that can do this?

Comment: look at the method substring, then post the code you tried. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @mindandmedia substring method won't help the author. Rethink.

Comment: str.substring(0,input) + "[" + str.substring(input,1) + "]" + str.substring(input+1); ?? i even find this the most readable, what's wrong with it, i dont have a compiler

Comment: it works, but I thought the varying parameters to substring() might be confusing for the readers.

Comment: one thing that's wrong about it: this is going to instantiate a lot of strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily with `StringBuilder`:

```
// Note that this will need to copy things *twice*, which may be less
// efficient than just calling replace once, but it's cleaner
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(text); 
builder.insert(index + 1, ']');
builder.insert(index, '[');
String newText = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

`myString = new StringBuilder(myString).insert(2, '[').insert(4,']').toString();`

StringBuilder is a cool class which helps to work with strings. It has `insert(int index, char c)` method which inserts given character to the specified location. As shown, you can create a new `StringBuilder` for your string, insert braces you need and convert it back to String using `toString()` method.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method in String class that can do it. StringBuffer and StringBuffer also has these methods.

```
        int index = 0;
        String input = "abcd";
        //System.out.println(Character.toString(input.charAt(index)));
        //System.out.println("["+input.charAt(index)+"]");
        String output = input.replace(Character.toString(input.charAt(index)), "["+input.charAt(index)+"]");
        System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: This will replace any occurrence of the same character, whereas the OP only wants to replace a single occurrence at a specific point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringBuffer` to do this.

```
String st = new String("abcd");
st = new StringBuffer(st).insert(index+1,"]").insert(index, "[").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html). It has got such methods.